# Get utxos for an address without rescanning the whole chain

Tags: bitcoin-core, address, bitcoin-cli, output-script-descriptors, utxo-management

In order to gather the utxos for an address `importdescriptors` will rescan the blockchain. Is there another way to get all the utxos for an address / descriptor without having to rescan the block chain?

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the current UTxOs for a descriptor, you can use the `scantxoutset` RPC command. It will scan the UTxO set but not the blockchain.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way I can do it to mimick that of Blockchain.com to scan for the utxo of any wallet address and return the response immediately?

Comment: You can call it for multiple addresses / descriptors at once. If you want something more efficient you are probably looking for a "scriptpubkey indexer", such as an electrum server: https://github.com/romanz/electrs/ .

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will check it out.